# JQuery DataTable plugin does nothing when added

Tags: jquery, playframework, datatables

I am trying to add Jquery's DataTables to my table because I would like the ability to sort and search the table.  I do not care about DataTable's styles as I already have my own plus some bootstrap styling.  I cannot seem to get the plugin to do anything though.

I am using the Java Play Framework and Jquery is incorporated into the template from elsewhere.

Template:

```
@(personList: List[Person])

@main("People") {
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dashboard-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for(person <- personList) {

            <tr>
                <td>@person.name</td>
                <td>@person.age</td>
                <td>@person.dob</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dashboard-table').DataTable();
    // other stuff
});
```

I have only included a single file for the DataTable functionality. `datatables.min.js` is located in my project's `project/public/javascripts/DataTables/datables.min.js` path.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try a console.log() on `$('#dashboard-table').DataTable();`. It should return an object with the DataTable api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Eric Guan's comment about logging `$('#dashboard-table').DataTable()`, I was able to figure out that this was a routing problem.  The logger did not print out the expected object.

Apparently, with the Play framework, you need to write your script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/DataTables/datatables.min.js")'></script>
```

I am new to Java Play so I did not realize this, but I was able to get DataTables working with this simple fix.  Hopefully this question helps out someone else in the future.